# Need to exclude specific record from large dataset in python

Tags: python, json, dataset, export-to-csv

So i have this dblp dataset where i need to exclude conferences . This is my code where i am converting json to csv but i need some changes in it so it can only copy papers other than conferences. my logic was to find conference in venue but the code is not working properly

```
import json
import csv

with open('test1.json') as lines, open('data3.csv', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as output:
    output = csv.DictWriter(output, ['abstract','authors','n_citation',"references","title","venue","year",'id'],lineterminator='\n')
    output.writeheader()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line[0] == '{' and line[-1] == '}':
            if line.find("conference")!=True:
                output.writerow(json.loads(line))
```

Here is sample json

```
{"abstract": "AdaBoost algorithm based on Haar-like features can achieves high accuracy (above 95%) in object detection.", 
"authors": ["Zheng Xu", "Runbin Shi", "Zhihao Sun", "Yaqi Li", "Yuanjia Zhao", "Chenjian Wu"], 
"n_citation": 0,
 "references": ["0a11984c-ab6e-4b75-9291-e1b700c98d52", "1f4152a3-481f-4adf-a29a-2193a3d4303c", "3c2ddf0a-237b-4d17-8083-c90df5f3514b", "522ce553-29ea-4e0b-9ad3-0ed4eb9de065", "579e5f24-5b13-4e92-b255-0c46d066e306", "5d0b987d-eed9-42ce-9bf3-734d98824f1b", "80656b4d-b24c-4d92-8753-bdb965bcd50a", "d6e37fb1-5f7e-448e-847b-7d1f1271c574"],
 "title": "A Heterogeneous System for Real-Time Detection with AdaBoost",
 "venue": "high performance computing and communications",
 "year": 2016,
 "id": "001eef4f-1d00-4ae6-8b4f-7e66344bbc6e"}


{"abstract": "In this paper, a kind of novel jigsaw EBG structure is designed and applied into conformal antenna array",
 "authors": ["Yufei Liang", "Yan Zhang", "Tao Dong", "Shan-wei Lu"], 
"n_citation": 0, 
"references": [], 
"title": "A novel conformal jigsaw EBG structure design", 
"venue": "international conference on conceptual structures", 
"year": 2016, 
"id": "002e0b7e-d62f-4140-b015-1fe29a9acbaa"}
```

The code works okay if i remove this line

```
if line.find("conference")!=True:
```

here is link to download sample json file

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1056yrc_Y4Y-tAZT52YUDxPPsWYsLcn48

smaller size json
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=57175973595937350188

Comment: Unless there's a valid JSON object on each line of the input file it's unlikely that the statement `output.writerow(json.loads(line))` would work. Please [edit] your question and add an sample what's in `test1.json` you're trying to process.

Comment: i have pasted the link in description.kindly check

Comment: The link you added is to a multi-megabyte JSON format file, I don't want to download the whole thing to help answer the question. Please create a _much_ smaller version and post a link to that in your question.

Comment: @martineau kindly check i have updated smaller version

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll take a look.

Comment: @martineau thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work. Since each line of your input file contains a complete JSON object, it first calls `json.loads()` to obtain a Python dictionary, and then checks the contents of the dictionary to see if it has a `"venue"` key and, if it does, whether the string value of that key contains the substring `"conference"`.

Also note I don't think you really need the:

```
        line = line.strip()
        if line[0] == '{' and line[-1] == '}':
```

part, but I left it in since I don't have your whole file. It's doesn't hurt, but does slow down processing to some degree.

```
import csv
import json


fields = 'abstract,authors,n_citation,references,title,venue,year,id'.split(',')

with open('test1.json') as lines, \
     open('data3.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output:
    output = csv.DictWriter(output, fields, lineterminator='\n')
    output.writeheader()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line[0] == '{' and line[-1] == '}':
            json_obj = json.loads(line)
            if 'conference' not in json_obj.get('venue', ''):
                output.writerow(json_obj)
```

**Modified** to answer (I think) a follow-on question in comments:

```
import collections
import csv
import json
from pprint import pprint


fields = 'abstract,authors,n_citation,references,title,venue,year,id'.split(',')
# Added.
venue_citations = collections.defaultdict(int)  # Total number of citations per venue.

with open('test1.json') as lines, \
     open('data3.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output:
    output = csv.DictWriter(output, fields, lineterminator='\n')
    output.writeheader()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line[0] == '{' and line[-1] == '}':
            json_obj = json.loads(line)
            venue = json_obj.get('venue', '')
            if 'conference' not in venue:
                output.writerow(json_obj)
                venue_citations[venue] += json_obj["n_citation"]  # Update count.

pprint(dict(venue_citations))
```

Comment: Thanks @marineau. Since i am new to python i have trouble finding total citation count of individual venue. Like i want to sum n_citations where venuee of different papers is same. Can you guide me

Comment: Umer iqbal: Not sure I understand that description of what you want to do, but have updated my answer with a guess.

Comment: Thanks for your great help but i think you misunderstood . so here is little example
in the dataset there are entries including Title, venue ,n_citations(which is citation count of that paper). now what i want to do is to traverse the dataset in a way that all citation count of specific venues sums up and stored in seperate csv
let me eleborate more
so lets suppose there are two papers both have same venue and one paper has citation 120 and other have 130. so i will pick the first paper venue and search it in whole dataset and then if found again add up its citaitons

Comment: so the new csv will just have these two columns . 1 = venue,2=total_citation_count_of_venue
basically want to sum up the citations of indivdiual venues and store in new csv

Comment: Umer iqbal: Sorry, but again I'm not completely sure I understand—besides, such involved follow-on questions aren't really appropriate on this website. That said, the code in my update is adding up the total number of citations for each unique venue name in the dataset and stores the total counts in a dictionary using the venue's name as the key. Seems like all you would have to do is write that to a `.csv` file using the key as the first column and the associated value as the second. I suggest you give that a try and post a new question if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily access the different fields with json module. If you are able to represent the json objects as a list in the test1.json file, you can call `json.load(open('test1.json','r'))` to load the json data as a list of json objects. If this is not possible, you can try the following.

```
import json

json_objs=list()

#iterate through the json data and create json objects
with open('test.json') as lines:
    s_buffer = list()

    for line in lines:
        s_buffer.append(line)
        if '}' in line:
            json_objs.append(json.loads(''.join(s_buffer)))
            s_buffer = list()

#check if each event is a conference or not
output_list = list()
for obj in json_objs:

    if not 'conference' in obj['venue']:
        output_list.append(obj)
```

trying to write to a file while processing the data might result in hit on performance, I am appending the output data to the `output_list` which can be used to write to csv file later.